# Do not understand vowel count code for javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
function getCount(str) {
  return (str.match(/[aeiou]/ig)||[]).length;
}
```

This code at code-war counts the amount of vowel in a string.It works perfectly fine; but, I trying to understand how it works.

Comment: it runs over the string that you send it and find all the 'aeiou' chars and return the amount of it(length of the array that you insert in to it.

Comment: What part exactly is the problem? The regular expression? The `||` operator?

Comment: `str.match(/[aeiou]/ig)` returns an array with all the characters that match the regex, and `.length` returns the length of the array.

Comment: This function uses [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to match against the letters [aeiou]. The 'ig' is telling the match that to match with no regard to upper/lowercase (letter 'i'), and to list all matches globally (letter 'g').

Comment: Got it thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/[aeiou]/ig` is [a regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) that will match any vowel. It will match any of `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, `u`, the `i` flag (/[aeiou]/**i**g) makes it case-insensitive and the `g` flag stands for "global" or in other words "don't stop after the first match".

The [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method takes a regular expression and returns any matches. So with the above regular expression, you would pass a word and return an array of all the vowels in it. For example

```js
var resultOfStringMatch = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".match(/[aeiou]/ig);

console.log(resultOfStringMatch)
```

There is a special case - if the initial string does not have any vowels, then the output would be the value `null`.

```js
var resultOfStringMatch = "Th qck brwn fx jmps vr th lzy dg".match(/[aeiou]/ig);

console.log(resultOfStringMatch)
```

For that purpose the `||[]` is used which [will return an empty array if the preceding value is falsey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429402/what-does-the-mean-in-javascript-array-creation?noredirect=1&lq=1).

```js
console.log(true || "some string");
console.log(false || "some string");

console.log(null || "null is a falsey value");
```

So, at the end the expression `str.match(/[aeiou]/ig)||[]` will *always* return an array. If you check its `length` property, you would find the number of vowels.